# Assigning a 2-digit unique code in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

can you please show me how to add a 2-digit unique code in every user's input.

The problem scenario is, if the program takes 4 inputs from the user (input1, input2, input3, input4), the program should also assign a unique 2-digit code in every input.

this is just a small part of my assignment, but if you could guide me through how to get it, it will be a great help for me. You may give me a hint if you feel don't want to give the real answer, but this one's quite important for me as once I've got this I can get through all the rest of the codes :)

here's what I have done so far:

## I want to utilise the numbers generated by this for loop. But, they should be used once only.

```
for i in range(99):
    rnd = print(f'{i:02}')
```

## Asking a user input.

```
Input1 = print(input("enter your first input: "))
Input2 = print(input("enter your second input: "))
Input3 = print(input("enter your third input: "))
Input4 = print(input("enter your fourth input: "))
```

here is the example output:

```
45 Input1
90 Input2
88 Input3
10 Input4
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Add the code you have so far and explain what's missing.

Comment: `from random import sample; sample(range(10, 100), 4)`? see [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=choice#random.sample).

Comment: Make a dictionary, have the key be a random number between 00 and 99 and the value be the input

Comment: apology for vague question. and thank you for all your hints, I will work that out from here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the codes from using `random.sample` of `4` within `range(10, 100)`, and save the inputs to a dict indexed by the codes:

```
import random
inputs = {}
for code in random.sample(range(10, 100), 4):
    inputs[code] = input('Input%d: ' % (len(inputs) + 1))
print(inputs)
```

Sample input and output:

```
Input1: hello
Input2: world
Input3: foo
Input4: bar
{60: 'hello', 21: 'world', 55: 'foo', 10: 'bar'}
```

Comment: this one's works for me, I actually need 6 digit random numbers, but it'll guide me through as a basis. Thank you very much